How to install a vertical divider in closet
In my local diy store, I can find these kind of rails. 
I'd like to use these and planks to build a simple closet.
However I'm not sure on how to build the central divider.
How should I go about this?
In black, walls with the above rails, in brown what I want to build.


Put two of what you've shown back to back is one way.

Indeed, if possible i'd like to avoid having a hole at the edge

Put a face frame over the front, or abandon these and learn to cut blind mortices, ideally blind sliding dovetails.

"Closet" = "shelves?"

@Huesmann well yes, there is a closet door in front though.
